# Testing @inject parent and @contentChildren together

Tags: angular, jasmine, angular-injector

I am developing a custom tab component composed by a parent and children like this:

**Parent**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-custom-tabs',
  template: `
  <div class="inline-flex">
    <ng-content select="app-custom-tab"></ng-content>
  </div>
  `
})
export class CustomTabsComponent {
  @ContentChildren(CustomTabComponent) _tabs: QueryList<CustomTabComponent>;
}
```

**Child**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-custom-tab',
  template: `
  <div>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </div>
  `
})
export class CustomTabComponent {
  constructor(@Inject(CustomTabsComponent) private _group: CustomTabsComponent) {
  }
}
```

Parent and children need to know each other. In runtime, I am not running any errors, but I can't manage to test it:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-fake',
  template: `
  <app-custom-tabs>
    <app-custom-tab> selected </app-custom-tab>
  </app-custom-tabs>
  `
}) class FakeComponent {
};

fdescribe('CustomTabsComponent', () => {
  let component: FakeComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<FakeComponent>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [FakeComponent, CustomTabsComponent, CustomTabComponent]
    }).compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(FakeComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

I am running `Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'CustomTabComponent' before initialization`; where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the components from `imports` to `declarations` since they are components.

Like this:

```
await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [FakeComponent, CustomTabsComponent, CustomTabComponent],
    }).compileComponents();
```

Comment: I tried and it still doesn't work

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure then.